# Best pre-Moon Lord armor?

Tags: terraria

So, my friends and I are getting ready to fight Moon Lord, but there's a big problem: We can't find a good armor set. I was hoping to get either the Stardust or Solar Flare armor, but now I realize that it needs Luminite which only drops from Moon Lord. What's the best armor before beating Moon Lord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last major boss before the Moon Lord is Plantera, whose defeat causes Chlorophyte to begin to spawn, which (eventually) gives you access to the following:

- Chlorophyte (Melee, Ranged, and Spell options)
- Shroomite (Chlorophyte + Glowing Mushrooms, Ranged damage)
- Spectre (Chlorophyte + Ectoplasm, Magic Damage)
- Turtle Armor (Chlorophyte + Turtle Shells, Defensive Melee)
- Beetle Armor (Turtle Armor + Beetle Husks, Defensive Melee, also requires golem to be defeated)
- Spooky Armor (Spooky Wood from the Pumpkin Moon, Summoner Armor)
  If you currently have these armors, there's nothing left to do but buckle down and face the Moon Lord as-is!